# Error with Conversion to Dalvik format failed and multidex in android?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-multidex

Whenever I try to import lib-c2callsdkres Library then Give the error like this,
[2015-01-05 18:29:30 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2015-01-05 18:29:30 - TestApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 and sometimes give me error for multidex.

How to solve this error.please suggest me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile using multidex. You have a lot of methods:

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html